# SQL Server Database synchronization with my project in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2005, c#-4.0

Sir,
I am having some problem regarding database in SQL Server.
My project is desktop application with login method....
My program is written in C# executes normally as I want with no errors in my queries...
But data is not stored back to database which the program inserts or updates... My database is created by visual studio 2010 as a separate mdf file in data folder... 
So kindly please help me in this. Here is a sample code :

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
     using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\Database_File.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"))
     {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from table_users where user_name='" + txtBoxUserName.Text + "' and user_password='" + txtBoxUserPass.Text + "' ",cn))
        {
          cn.Open();                        
          dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
          while (dr.Read())
          {
            if (dr["user_name"].ToString() == txtBoxUserName.Text && dr["user_password"].ToString() == txtBoxUserPass.Text)
            {
              ...
              ...
              try
              {
                using (SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("insert into table_user(id,user_name,user_status) values(" + key + "," + active_user_name + "',"+ user_status + ")",cn))
                {
                  cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                  Thread form_name = new Thread(new ThreadStart(thread_Proc_form_name));
                  form_name.Start();
                }
              }
              catch  { throw;}
            }
          }
        }
     }
  }
  catch  { throw;}
}
```

The program runs as i want but when i look into the database table no changes are saved. For eg : when I login then no information of login is shown in the database on next run..
Same is the case for register... every time i run the app I have to register again and again. I don't know where is the error. Please help me sir where i am going wrong....

Thanks & Regards
Saurabh Mahajan

Comment: Note that TRY CATCH {throw;} is a default behavior. You can remove these and it won't change anything to your application

Comment: thanks sir...but using try catch is just an option for small applications... we use it or not it hardly affect the problem...

Comment: Please point out where the code is suppose to update the database, because I don't see it! If it's cmd1, it's an empty insert query!

Comment: And your TRY CATCH are there even if you don't write them. It's implicitly there. It's only noise in your code.

Comment: i have edit the ques for insert and select query...
Thanks Sir....

Comment: Rebuilding the app will replace your data file each time.

Comment: is there any sort of error for file replacement..??? please provide me some help with some tutorial or exaple code... thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This snippet suggests to me that you've got a `Database_File.mdf` in your solution in Visual Studio:

```
AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\Database_File.mdf
```

Each time you build your project, `Database_File.mdf` will be copied to the output directory, overwriting whatever file was there previously.

This behaviour is by design.

Note that [user instances are deprecated](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143684%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), you should consider attaching your `Database_File.mdf` to your SQL Express instance for the duration of development or using something like SQL Server LocalDB.

Comment: so u mean that instead of |DataDirectory|\\Database_File.mdf i should connect the database with sql server right..??

Comment: @Saurabh For the purposes of development I'd use a database on your SQL Server. Note, however, if you're developing against it you're probably going to make mistakes and mess stuff up, which is why VS overwrites your database with a good copy, each time. Later, you might want to get the final `.mdf` out of SQL Server and package that with your application, using User Instances (even though they're deprecated) or SQL Server LocalDB.

Comment: Thanks alot sir, for explaining in detail for now i should work using sql server....
Thanks & Regards
Saurabh Mahajan

Answer (score 0):

To connect to SQL Server from C#.NET, you need to create a connection string such as below:

```
private SqlConnection connection; 
private string connectionString = @"Server=(local);Database=Embedding_SQL_Test;User ID=sa;Password=123"; connection = new SqlConnection( connectionString );
```

Next, you use the `SqlConnection` object created above to create a `SqlCommand`, as shown below:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand( "select * from Customer where CustomerID = @Cid", connection);
```

The SQL query shown here can be replaced by a SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE queries etc.

Next to execute the SQL queries in the database, you use the following methods: `ExecuteReader` - to execute SELECT queries, `ExecuteNonQuery` - to execute INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE, and SET statements.

This is a very short description of how to connect to SQL Server database from C# and execute SQL queries in the database. For details about the connection string, the methods and their parameters check the following link: ( http://www.shahriarnk.com/Shahriar-N-K-Research-Embedding-SQL-in-C-Sharp-Java.html ) Here you will also find details about how to pass parameters to the SQL queries as well as calling stored procedures and much more.